# want to show two datepicker adjacent

Tags: extjs, datepicker, extjs4, rally

facing some issues while showing two datepicker on same panel. Want to show two datepicker adjacent 
[image]

See the above screenshot.And my code

`var datePicker = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
                        title: 'Choose a PSI Dates',
                        width: 400,
                        //bodyPadding: 10,
                        //height: 200,
                        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
                        items: [{
                            xtype: 'datepicker',
                            minDate: minDate,
                            handler: function(picker, date) {
                                 that.onDateSelected(date);
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            xtype: 'datepicker',
                            minDate: minDate,
                            handler: function(picker, date) {
                                 that.onDateSelected(date);
                            }

                        }
                        ]
                    });`

Any suggestions on this. please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think layout type `hbox` should solve your problem.

```
var datePicker = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
                        title: 'Choose a PSI Dates',
                        width: 400,
                        layout: {
                            type: 'hbox',
                        },
                        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
                        items: [{
                            xtype: 'datepicker',
                            minDate: minDate,
                            handler: function(picker, date) {
                                 that.onDateSelected(date);
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            xtype: 'datepicker',
                            minDate: minDate,
                            handler: function(picker, date) {
                                 that.onDateSelected(date);
                            }

                        }
                        ]
                    });
```

Comment: One more doubt I have, how should I use this two datepicker as start_date and end_date to call some other function after selecting both the dates..Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is an event, change( this, newDate, oldDate, eOpts ),which is called after you select a date,you can implement this event function,and call your own function from inside this method.